# Twitching TABLE in simple HTML/JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm learning with a simple JavaScript puzzle, where you have to place eight queens on the chessboard so that no two attack each other. Below is a snapshot.

Problem: whenever a queen is placed in an unoccupied column, that column jerks for a pixel or two. How can I fix this with fixing the column width? The SVG image of the queen figure is obviously smaller than `60 px`. My CSS is below.

Should I show my JavaScript and HTML files as well? [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_srk4ofLN22VUZyNlJvbGU2RTA/edit?usp=sharing) are the files on my Google Drive (17 KB).

On this note, can I upload complete project somwhere and run/link it from there?

```
table {
    width: 480px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
    height: 60px;
}

td {
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Add the HTML, CSS and JavaScript to http://jsfiddle.net/ click Save and share the link

Comment: Seems like a Table CSS issue, usually I draw a <div> inside the table and unhide the div (queen) when clicked. Have posted a `SVG` solution, anyone wants to post a `canvas` solution?

Answer (score 0):

The board and queen placement can be written with jQuery and SVG only. Here's a simple example (without the queen logic, so you can place a queen on every cell).

Update: tested on IE9, Firefox and Chrome (Oct 2014)

```js
jQuery('svg').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log("x,y: ", e.pageX, ',', e.pageY);
  // determine position of nearest square, top left cell of 48px square starts at ccoordinates (9,9), 
  var cols = parseInt((e.pageX- 9) / 48);
  var rows = parseInt((e.pageY- 9) / 48);
  var cell_id =  cols+'_'+rows;  

   if ((cols < 8) && (rows < 8) && (jQuery('#'+cell_id).length == 0) ){
    jQuery('#cell_location').text('('+cols+','+rows+')');
    // insert an image in that cell
    var queen = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    queen.setAttributeNS(null, "id", cell_id);
    queen.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#queen");
    queen.setAttributeNS(null, "x", (cols*48) + 1);
    queen.setAttributeNS(null, "y", (rows*48) + 1);
    jQuery('svg').append(queen);
   } 
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 450 450" height="450" width="450" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  <defs>
      <g id="queen" style="opacity:1; fill:#ffffff; fill-opacity:1; fill-rule:evenodd; stroke:#000000; stroke-width:1.5; stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4; stroke-dasharray:none; stroke-opacity:1;">
    <path
      d="M 9 13 A 2 2 0 1 1  5,13 A 2 2 0 1 1  9 13 z"
      transform="translate(-1,-1)" />
    <path
      d="M 9 13 A 2 2 0 1 1  5,13 A 2 2 0 1 1  9 13 z"
      transform="translate(15.5,-5.5)" />
    <path
      d="M 9 13 A 2 2 0 1 1  5,13 A 2 2 0 1 1  9 13 z"
      transform="translate(32,-1)" />
    <path
      d="M 9 13 A 2 2 0 1 1  5,13 A 2 2 0 1 1  9 13 z"
      transform="translate(7,-4.5)" />
    <path
      d="M 9 13 A 2 2 0 1 1  5,13 A 2 2 0 1 1  9 13 z"
      transform="translate(24,-4)" />
    <path
      d="M 9,26 C 17.5,24.5 30,24.5 36,26 L 38,14 L 31,25 L 31,11 L 25.5,24.5 L 22.5,9.5 L 19.5,24.5 L 14,10.5 L 14,25 L 7,14 L 9,26 z "
      style="stroke-linecap:butt;" />
    <path
      d="M 9,26 C 9,28 10.5,28 11.5,30 C 12.5,31.5 12.5,31 12,33.5 C 10.5,34.5 10.5,36 10.5,36 C 9,37.5 11,38.5 11,38.5 C 17.5,39.5 27.5,39.5 34,38.5 C 34,38.5 35.5,37.5 34,36 C 34,36 34.5,34.5 33,33.5 C 32.5,31 32.5,31.5 33.5,30 C 34.5,28 36,28 36,26 C 27.5,24.5 17.5,24.5 9,26 z "
      style="stroke-linecap:butt;" />
    <path
      d="M 11.5,30 C 15,29 30,29 33.5,30"
      style="fill:none;" />
    <path
      d="M 12,33.5 C 18,32.5 27,32.5 33,33.5"
      style="fill:none;" />
  </g>
    </defs>
<g id="gridlines"><path stroke="#d7d7d7" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="3,3" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" d="M0,0 L0,384 M48,0 L48,384 M96,0 L96,384 M144,0 L144,384 M192,0 L192,384 M240,0 L240,384 M288,0 L288,384 M336,0 L336,384 M0,0 L384,0 M0,48 L384,48 M0,96 L384,96 M0,144 L384,144 M0,192 L384,192 M0,240 L384,240 M0,288 L384,288 M0,336 L384,336 "/><path stroke="#00f50f" stroke-dasharray="3,3" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" d="M0,0 L0,384 M384,0 L384,384 M0,0 L384,0 M0,384 L384,384 "/></g>
  <text alignment-baseline="baseline" text-anchor="start" id="cell_location" x="400" y="30">Hello</text>
</svg>
```